# Python Django open huge file

Tags: python, json, django, memory

I want to build a json service with python. Program will read a json file then return. My file size 1 GB. When I run the program, I have error that "MemoryError". My code is;

```
def homepage(request):
  file = open("file.json")
  json_file = json.load(file)
  return JsonResponse(json_file)
```

Can anybody help me. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Trying to read 1GB files in memory is indeed not a good idea, and FWIW using "monolithic" json for huge datasets is pushing the boundaries. There are mainly three solutions to this problem, depending on your use case:

1. using a streaming json parser like [ijson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson)
2. using the [jsonlines format](http://jsonlines.org/)
3. and of course the most obvious: paginating your json content (which is what most existing rest/json API do)

The first two solutions are (obviously) mostly effective for "consumer" code. Here you are actually on the "producer" side (the fact that your json is stored in a flat file etc being an implementation detail, totally irrelevant to the clients), so the obvious solution is to split your json in sensiblly sized chunks and serve it paginated (preferably adding the current page, total page count and a link to the next page in the response to make the client's work easier).

Answer (score 0):

Could you take advantage of Django's StreamingHttpResponse class?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse

From their docs: The StreamingHttpResponse class is used to stream a response from Django to the browser. You might want to do this if generating the response takes too long or uses too much memory. For instance, it’s useful for generating large CSV files. It needs an iterator but I think you could open the file in such a way that you return an iterator per line versus the entire file.